# Error in the Django tutorial: urls.py

Tags: django, url

I just upgraded my Django to version 1.9.6. I was doing the [basic tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/) but I have a Syntax Error in the urls.py.

Note: I changed the name "mysite" to "polls", and "polls" to "poll".

This is my code in polls/poll/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^, views.index, name='index'),
]
```

And this is the error message:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x03AE16F0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\David\Dropbox\Emprendimiento\Gamification\polls\polls\urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    url(r'^poll/', include('poll.urls')),
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 52, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1467, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1572, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\David\Dropbox\Emprendimiento\Gamification\polls\poll\urls.py", line 6
    url(r'^, views.index, name='index'),
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed out the `'` to end the string (before the comma in `r'^,`. Ideally, you should add a `$` as well:

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

Note that your text editor or IDE may do syntax highlighting to help you spot this question - note that in your question, Stack Overflow has all of `^, views.index, name=` in the same colour, to show that it's a single string.

Comment: Thank you very much @Alasdair. But now I'm getting this message:
""""
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in polls.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^poll/
^admin/
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
"""

Your answer makes sense, but I only copied and pasted.

Comment: That 404 is expected. You haven't defined a url for `/` yet, you defined it for `/poll/` (because of the include). The tutorial tells you to go to `http://localhost:8000/polls/`, not `http://localhost:8000`. In your case, go to `http://localhost:8000/poll/`, or change the include to `^polls/'`.

Comment: Of course!, thank you very much @Alasdair. You saved me hours.